# How to paste values across multiple worksheets in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Could anyone share knowledge about how to paste values from one worksheet to multiple worksheets, starting from a specific column?

I want to copy formulas from the worksheet ("Template") and paste it to other worksheets starting from the column F1 all the way to the last column/row. Following is my codes. I was stuck from Line 5 and can't figure a way to paste values without looking at the names of the sheets. Could anyone advise how to solve this challenge? Thank you :)

```
Dim Y as workbook
Set Y = Thisworkbook
Dim copydata as Long
copydata=y.worksheets("Template").UsedRange.Rows.Count
Dim i as Long
For i=3 to sheets.count
Y.worksheets("name").Range("F1:x"&copydata).Formula= _
Y.worksheets("Template").Range("F1:X"&copydata).Formula
```

Comment: Can you provide your sheet names? Are your sheet names in a specific order? Also could you please provide your entire snippet? You're missing a `Next i` here.

Comment: Change your `For` loop to a `For Each` loop like `For Each ws in Y.Worksheets`. Then inside the loop you can do `If ws.name <> "Template" Then ws.Range("F1:X" & copyData.Formula = y.Worksheets("Template").Range("F1:X"&copydata).Formula`  Completing the loop after copying with `Next ws`.

Comment: @JNevill - make that an answer, not a comment

Comment: That would be easier to read, right? ;)

Comment: Thanks for the advice! My sheet names don't come in a specific order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code from my comment above. Suggestion is to switch to a `For Each` loop to iterate through all of the worksheets in your workbook. You can employ an `If` block to test and skip any sheet where you don't want to copy this formula ("Template" would be the one I know for a fact you should skip).

```
Dim Y as workbook
Set Y = Thisworkbook

Dim copydata as Long
copydata=y.worksheets("Template").UsedRange.Rows.Count

Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws in Y.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Template" Then ws.Range("F1:x"&copydata).Formula = _
            y.worksheets("Template").Range("F1:X"&copydata).Formula
Next ws
```

Comment: I added a "End If" above the "Next ws" and it works perfect! Thank you for your suggestion, JNevill.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same index that you are using to loop through the worksheets collection.

```
Dim Y as workbook, copydata as Long, i as Long

Set Y = Thisworkbook

copydata=y.worksheets("Template").UsedRange.Rows.Count

For i=3 to worksheets.count
    Y.worksheets(i).Range("F1:x"&copydata).Formula= _
      Y.worksheets("Template").Range("F1:X"&copydata).Formula
next i
```